# Adding javascript function to Vaadin

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I want to add a javascript function to vaadin so it would be performed when the button is pressed. So far I have tried it these two ways.

```
String string = "function myFunction(p) {"
    +"alert(p);"
+"}"
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(string);
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("myFunction('Hello');");
```

And

```
String string = "function myFunction(p1, p2) {"
    +"alert(p);"
+"}"
+"myFunction('Hello');"
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(string);
```

Buth both ways ended with no successful result.

**Update**:
I changed the codes so they will print something. Those two codes still doesn't work.

Comment: how do you determine, that it's not successful?

Comment: What is getCurrent() expected to be/return?

Comment: @cfrick I changed the code so it should print something to the screen. My original function (not this toy function) is rather complicated, so instead I posted something simple that doesn't work as well.

Comment: @user44697 then you might want to add more context. see this minimal example, where the two alerts trigger https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/3aac3fc9943366d9ec5a

Comment: @AndréSchild getCurrent() returns the instance of currently processed page.

Comment: You will then have to look in firebug or similar if your js is delivered correctly to the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your `myFunction` is not registered anywhere when you try to call it. What I mean by this your code:

```
String string = "function myFunction(p) {"
    +"alert(p);"
+"}"
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(string);
```

have no effect. To properly define a function in JavaScript using Vaadin you need to assign it to a some variable. This simple change will enable your code to run:

```
String string = "soReadyToHelp = function myFunction(p) {"
        +"alert(p);"
    +"}";
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(string);
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("soReadyToHelp('Hello');");
```

Note that, when integrating Vaadin and JavaScript you may find [AbstractJavaScriptComponent](https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.1/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractJavaScriptComponent.html) useful.